# PHP multiQuery issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having a bit of an issue regarding multi-querying with PHP. My database has the following tables, with their schema shown below:

First table - Users

```
(PK) UserID,
UserFullName

UserID      FullName

1000        Arthur Whitney

 2000       Alex Schwartz

 3000       Eva Kilpatrick
```

Second table - Invites

```
(PK) RowID,
InvName, InvSender, InvSenderTotal, InvReceiver, InvReceiverTotal, InvStatus

RowID  InvName InvSenderID InvSenderTotal InvReceiverID InvReceiverTotal InvStatus

  1     Fair     1000       10             2000          10            Sent

  2     Party    2000       45             1000          45            Sent

  3     Cinema   2000       12             1000          12            Sent

  4    Vacation  3000       15             1000          5            Expired
```

Say for example when user Alex Schwartz, with unique ID 2000, is logged in, I would like to have it that he can see the name of the invite, the invite sender's name (if he is the invite receiver), the invite receiver's name (if he is the invite sender) and both the invite sender and receiver's totals.

I have devised the following two queries, which yield the results that I intended:

QUERY1

```
select i.InvName, i.InvSenderTotal, i.InvReceiverTotal, u.FullName FROM Invites as i INNER JOIN Users as u ON u.UserID = i.InvReceiverID 
WHERE i.InvStatus = 'Sent' AND i.InvSenderID = 2000
```

This shows me the Invite Name, Invite Sender and Receivers' totals and the Invite Receiver's name when Alex Schwartz was sending the invite. Expected output here would be specific details of Row IDs 2 and 3.

The following query shows the inverse:

QUERY2

```
select i.InvName, i.InvSenderTotal, i.InvReceiverTotal, u.FullName FROM Invites as i INNER JOIN Users as u ON u.UserID = i.InvSenderID 
WHERE i.InvStatus = 'Sent' AND i.InvReceiverID = 2000
```

So this enables Alex Schwartz to see the name of the person who sent the invite, along with the same data. Expected output here would be specific details of Row ID 1.

Hence, I am able to get the data I want, but I require two different queries in order to get it. This has presented problems in PHP whereby only one query seems to carry out. So my question is essentially, does anyone know how I could combine these two queries into one? I am also aware of multiQuerying and have tried to implement this, but have not had much success with that either.

Thanks in advance of your help.

Comment: The problem which actually seems to be necessary to solve, is why does it present a problem in PHP when you run two SELECT queries?

Comment: I'm not actually sure myself. Whenever I ran the two queries in PHP it seemed like only the first one completed successfully. I even ran the queries in phpMyAdmin and ascertained that the second query was getting the data I needed. That's why I looked into the multiQuery function briefly yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `UNION`.

```
select i.InvName, i.InvSenderTotal, i.InvReceiverTotal, u.FullName FROM Invites as i INNER JOIN Users as u ON u.UserID = i.InvReceiverID 
WHERE i.InvStatus = 'Sent' AND i.InvSenderID = 2000
UNION
select i.InvName, i.InvSenderTotal, i.InvReceiverTotal, u.FullName FROM Invites as i INNER JOIN Users as u ON u.UserID = i.InvSenderID 
WHERE i.InvStatus = 'Sent' AND i.InvReceiverID = 2000
```

Comment: Good point! I had forgotten about that function. Thanks for the editing and help you provided.

Comment: @appreciateYourHelp Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

As a note, you can do this without `union all` (which is preferred over `union` unless you intentionally need to remove duplicates):

```
select i.InvName, i.InvSenderTotal, i.InvReceiverTotal, u.FullName
FROM Invites i INNER JOIN
     Users u
     ON u.UserID IN (i.InvReceiverID, i.InvSenderID)
WHERE i.InvStatus = 'Sent' AND i.InvSenderID = 2000;
```